# How do I know that the preimage of a topology is the whole topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ have the trivial topology and $X$ be an arbitrary topological space. Show that every function $f \colon X \to Y$ is continuous.

I know that to show a function is continuous, I have to show that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ for every open set $V$ in $Y$.

Since $Y$ has the trivial topology, there are only two open sets: the empty set and $Y$. I know that the pre-image of empty is empty, and therefore open in every topology. But how am I sure that the pre-image of $Y$ is all of $X$? I don't know what point I am missing in the understanding of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down to what it means for $f$ to be a function. Every point in $X$ is sent to some point in $Y$ by $f$. That is, $f^{-1}(Y) = \{ x \in X \;|\; f(x) \in Y\} = X$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f^{-1}(Y)=\{x\in X\,|\,f(x)\in Y\}=X.$$ The last equality follows from the fact that the function $f$ maps from $X$ to $Y$, so for *every* $x\in X$, one has $f(x)\in Y$.